# Foreign key not inserted into ecto table

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm learning Elixir and now creating an application with a `users` table and a `user_informations` table. I'm trying to query for `user_id` in `user_informations` but it was not inserted, and I don't understand why because all other fields were inserted.

Here's the user_informations table:

```
def change do
  create table(:user_informations, primary_key: false) do
    add :user_information_id, :uuid, primary_key: true
    add :user_id, references(:users, [column: :user_id, type: :uuid])
    add :full_name, :string
    add :job_title, :string
    add :address, :string
    add :city, :string
    add :country, :string
    add :phone_number, :integer
    add :bio, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  create unique_index(:user_informations, [:user_information_id])
end
```

The UserInformation model:

```
defmodule MyApp.Accounts.UserInformation do
  use Ecto.Schema
  alias MyApp.Accounts
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:user_information_id, Ecto.UUID, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type Ecto.UUID
  schema "user_informations" do
    field :full_name, :string
    field :job_title, :string
    field :address, :string
    field :city, :string
    field :country, :string
    field :phone_number, :integer
    field :bio, :string

    belongs_to :users, Accounts.User, foreign_key: :user_id

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def user_details_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
      |> cast(params, [:full_name, :job_title, :address, :city, :country, :phone_number, :bio])
      |> validate_required([:full_name])
      |> validate_length(:full_name, min: 2)
  end
end
```

The function inserting the changeset of `user_informations`:

```
  def update(conn, %{"user_information" => user_information_params}) do
    current_user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
    user_information_changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(current_user, :user_informations,
        full_name: user_information_params["full_name"],
        job_title: user_information_params["job_title"],
        address: user_information_params["address"],
        city: user_information_params["city"],
        country: user_information_params["country"],
        phone_number: user_information_params[:phone_number],
        bio: user_information_params["bio"])

    Repo.insert(user_information_changeset)
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Success!")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: The `user_id` argument must be given as an extra argument to the changeset.

```
user_information_changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(current_user, :user_informations,
        full_name: user_information_params["full_name"],
        ...
        user_id: current_user.user_id)
```

Comment: I think build_assoc should handle that for you automatically, probably you are missing something.

Comment: You're correct, apparently `current_user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)` doesn't return the `user_id` the way Ecto expects. Therefore, I removed `build_assoc` and implemented the changeset as `%UserInformation{user_id: current_user.user_id, ....}`. Now it works and in the correct manner.